# Why does this function using a typeclass with overlapping instances behave differently in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, ghci, overlapping-instances

## Background

I have written the following code in Haskell (GHC 8.6.3):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE 
  NoImplicitPrelude,
  MultiParamTypeClasses,
  FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts,
  TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances,
  AllowAmbiguousTypes
#-}

import Prelude(Char, Show, show, undefined, id)

data Nil
nil :: Nil
nil = undefined

instance Show Nil where
  show _ = "nil"

data Cons x xs = Cons x xs 
  deriving Show

class FPack f r where
  fpack :: f -> r

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} f ~ (Nil -> r) => FPack f r where
  fpack f = f nil

instance (FPack (x -> b) r, f ~ (Cons a x -> b)) => FPack f (a -> r) where
  fpack f a = fpack (\x -> f (Cons a x))
```

The idea behind this code is to produce a function of variable arity that takes its arguments and packs them into a heterogeneous list.

For example, the following

```hs
fpack id "a" "b" :: Cons [Char] (Cons [Char] Nil)
```

produces the list `Cons "a" (Cons "b" nil)`.

## Problem

In general, I want to call `fpack` by passing `id` as its `f` parameter (like above) so I wish to define the following function as a shorthand:

```hs
pack = fpack id
```

If I load the above program into GHCi and execute the above line, pack is defined as desired and its type (as given by `:t`) is `FPack (a -> a) r => r`.
So I defined the function like so in my program:

```hs
pack :: FPack (a -> a) r => r
pack = fpack id
```

But this gives the following error when loading said program into GHCi:

```
bugs\so-pack.hs:31:8: error:
    * Overlapping instances for FPack (a0 -> a0) r
        arising from a use of `fpack'
      Matching givens (or their superclasses):
        FPack (a -> a) r
          bound by the type signature for:
                     pack :: forall a r. FPack (a -> a) r => r
          at bugs\so-pack.hs:30:1-29
      Matching instances:
        instance [overlappable] (f ~ (Nil -> r)) => FPack f r
          -- Defined at bugs\so-pack.hs:24:31
        instance (FPack (x -> b) r, f ~ (Cons a x -> b)) =>
                 FPack f (a -> r)
          -- Defined at bugs\so-pack.hs:27:10
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of `a0, r')
    * In the expression: fpack id
      In an equation for `pack': pack = fpack id
   |
31 | pack = fpack id
   |
```

This leads me to my questions. Why does this function work when defined in GHCi, but not when defined in the program proper? Is there a way I can make this work in the program proper? If so, how?

## My Thoughts

From what I understand about GHC and Haskell, this error comes from the fact that `pack` could resolve to either one of the two overlapping instances, and that bothers GHC. However, I thought that the `AllowAmbiguousTypes` option should solve that problem by deferring instance selection to the final call site. Unfortunately, that apparently that isn't sufficient. I am curious as to why, but I am even more curious as to why GHCi accepts this definition in its REPL loop but it does not accept it when it is inside a program.

## A Tangent

I have another question regarding this program that is not directly related to main thrust of this question, but I thought it might be wise to ask it here rather than create another question about the same program.

As seen in the example above i.e.

```hs
fpack id "a" "b" :: Cons [Char] (Cons [Char] Nil)
```

I have to provide an explicit type signature to `fpack` in order for it to work as desired. If I don't provide one (i.e. just call `fpack id "a" "b"`), GHCi produces the following error:

```
<interactive>:120:1: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Cons [Char] (Cons [Char] Nil)' with `()'
        arising from a use of `it'
    * In the first argument of `System.IO.print', namely `it'
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: System.IO.print it
```

Is there any way I could alter the definition of `fpack` to get GHC to infer the proper type signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate `fpack` manually.

```
pack :: forall a r . FPack (a -> a) r => r
pack = fpack @(a->a) @r id
```

This requires `ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes`.

Alternatively, provide a type for `id`.

```
pack :: forall a r . FPack (a -> a) r => r
pack = fpack (id :: a -> a)
```

The issue it that GHC can't see if it should use the `fpack` provided by that `FPack (a->a) r` constraint. That might be puzzling at first, but note that `fpack (id :: T -> T)` could also correctly generate `r` if there is some `instance FPack (T -> T) r` available. Since `id` could be both `a -> a` and `T -> T` (for any `T`), GHC can not safely choose.

One can see this phenomenon in the type error, since GHC mentions `a0`. That type variable stands for some type which might be `a`, but might also be something else. One then can try to guess why the code isn't forcing `a0 = a`, pretending there are other instances around that could be used instead.

Comment: Huh. That works! Thanks! Some curiosities: How should one know to do this and why is this not needed in GHCi? Also, any advice on my tangential question?

Comment: @tophat GHCi uses the "extended default rules" where in some erroneous/ambiguous cases it defaults type variables in an aggressive way, often to `()`. That's done so that entering `[]` in GHCi does not cause an error -- that would be equivalent to `print []` which is ambiguous since e.g. an empty list of ints is printed differently from an empty list of chars. I don't know if it's possible to make GHCi infer the proper signature -- variadic functions do not fit well in Haskell's type system.